# How to get Bitters working in Jekyll?

Tags: rubygems, sass, jekyll, bourbon

I have been using Bourbon and Neat in Jekyll with no problems. I am now trying to add Bitters to the mix, but am having problems. I have installed Bitters using `gem install bitters` and it works in non-Jekyll projects.

My `_config.yml` file contains `gems: [bourbon, bitters, neat]`. My `scss` file contains

```
@import 'bourbon';
@import 'base/base';
@import 'neat';
```

The error I get when I try to serve Jekyll is

```
File to import not found or unreadable: bitters.
Load paths: 
  C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bourbon-4.1.1/app/assets/stylesheets  
  C:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/neat-1.7.1/app/assets/stylesheets on line 4
```

I have tried editing `_grid_settings.scss` as per the instructions [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bitters#installation), but to no avail.

**Edit**

[Here](https://github.com/Lyapu/jekyllBitters) is the code on GitHub. The line `@import 'base/base';` is commented out in `_sass/_base.scss` in order to get it to run.

Comment: Your code can help. Any repository url ?

Comment: Hi David. I added a repo [here](https://github.com/Lyapu/jekyllBitters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to `gem install bitters`

Uncomment the `@import 'base/base';` in `_sass/base.scss`

Then

```
cd _sass
bitters install
cd ..
jekyll serve
```

Works perfect here on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: This gives me a new error: `Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'css/main.scss': Invalid CSS after "@": expected identifier, was " import "../nea..." on line 2`.

Comment: Bitters is broken, I've opened a bug here https://github.com/thoughtbot/bitters/issues/154. In `_sass/base/_grid_settings.scss` replace `@ import "../neat/neat-helpers"` by  `@import "../neat/neat-helpers";` and your good to go !

Comment: I think that might have been my mistake when following these instructions: `If you are using Bitters and Neat without Ruby on Rails, you need to change the import for neat-helpers inside _grid-settings.scss to "../neat/neat-helpers"`. I just did a fresh install without modifying `_grid-settings.scss` and it seems to be working now. So why is it that I need to manually do `bitters install` in the `_sass` directory? Previously, Bourbon and Neat were working just by including `gems: [bourbon, neat]`. I didn't have to do a `bourbon install` in my Jekyll directory.

Comment: So it was you, not the gem. I've closed the issue on bitters. Concerning the `bourbon install` no need for me. Just `bitters install` and all runs well.

Comment: I noticed that the bitters installation *must* be inside the `_sass` folder. Where are the settings for this? I am trying it on another project now that does not have a `_sass` folder, and I would rather not create one just for the sake of preserving hard-coded paths. Do you know how I can change this?

Answer (score 0):

For others running into this problem in the future, I was able to resolve this issue by adding the directory containing my "base/base" bitters installation to my _config.yml

e.g. for `"base/base"` in the `css` folder add

`sass:
  sass_dir: css`

to your `_config.yml`